# Dynamic way to read positional file with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am able to read positional/fixed length file with the help of below code statically.but I need to make it dynamic like-  we need to pass position of the file and file name as a parameter.

```
val positionalFileReading = spark.read.textFile(inputFilePath).rdd
  .map(l => (l.substring(0, 3).trim(), l.substring(3, 13).trim(), 
             l.substring(13,18).trim(), l.substring(18,22).trim()))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend using a method to split your row at several points:

```
def splitAtLengths(row: String, lengths: List[Int], acc: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = lengths match {
  case Nil => acc.reverse
  case n :: ls => 
    val (first, rest)  row.splitAt(n)
    splitAtLengths(rest, ls, first :: acc)
}
```

This will allow you to do `splitAtLengths(l, List(3, 10, 5)).map(_.trim)` to replace what you have in your `map`.

Now, you just have to give the relevant parameters to your function:

```
def positionalFileReading(inputFilePath: String, cellLengths: List[Int]) = spark.read.textFile(inputFilePath).rdd.
  map(l => splitAtLengths(l, cellLengths).map(_.trim))
```

Comment: By using above method I am able to read the positional file but out put is not as expected output given in single column I want it on different columns from dataframes:- current op:

| Value |

[ 56,apple,TRUE,0.56]

[ 45,pear,FALSE,1.34]

required op-

| _1| _2| _3| _4|

| 56| apple| TRUE|0.56|

| 45| pear|FALSE|1.34|